# NavigationController внутри TabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios

Стоит задача - реализовать на одной из вкладок TabBar'а выпадающий список с вариантами выбора (своего рода радиобаттон). Насколько сумел разузнать, это реализуется применением NavigationController. Однако, нигде не смог найти, как уместить табличное представление, табы, навигацию, и организовать взаимодействие между ними. Как это выглядит концептуально, или где об этом можно внятно почитать (желательно на русском)?

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю используете ли вы интерфейс билдер, но программно легко делается.
В appDelegate создаете UITabBarController, у него есть свойство viewControllers - это массив состоящий из UIVIewController'ов или его наследников.Таким образом каждый элемент массива viewControllers будет отдельной вкладкой(если их больше 5 то автоматически добавится вкладка More).Добавляете UITabBarCOntroller  в UIWindow как rootViewController.
Если вам навигация нужна внутри каждой вкладки, то делате следующее:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];//можно сделать просто init и не указывать явно размер.

UIViewController *vcWithRadioButtons = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vcWithRadioButtons];
[arrayOfViewControllers addObject:nav];
[nav release];[vcWithRadioButtons release];

...//Повторяете еще n раз (в моем случае 3 т.к. я сделал массив на  4 элемента)процесс создания UIViewController'а, UINavigationContoller'a  и добавление его в массив.

UITabBarController *tbController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tbController.viewControllers = arrayOfViewControllers;
[arrayOfViewControllers release];
self.window.rootViewController = tbController;
[tbController release];
```

В общем то и все. Получили таб бар с 4мя вкладками, в каждой из которых есть навигация. Дальше уже реализуйте контроллер с радиокнопками.

Концептуально:

UIWindow->UITabBarController
                            ->UINavigatinController->UIVIewController

```
                        ->UINavigatinController->UIVIewController
                        ->UINavigatinController->UIVIewController
                        ->UINavigatinController->UIVIewController
```

Как-то так. ;)
Конкретно того, что вы спрашивали [здесь](http://www.imaladec.net/) нет, но есть другое, и на русско ;)

Comment: Хороший способ,  перешол на него, когда отказался от использования .xib файлов.
Такими строчками можно прикрепить картинки и названия к вкладкам)))

**vcWithRadioButtons1.title = @"UITabBarSystemItemTopRated";**
 
**vcWithRadioButtons1.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemTopRated tag:1];**